# How to fix/disable the high-CPU "find" process?

Tags: performance, cpu

Using a MacBook Air (OS 12.4) I noticed that after a reboot (because the mac was running very slow), the mac started to run very slow. I also noticed a process named "find" which was using like 10-40% CPU usage for like 30 minutes.

According to [this page](https://osxdaily.com/2010/11/27/the-find-process-in-mac-os-x/) this process is used to "clears caches, updates system databases, and removes temporary files".

I wonder how many caches, system databases and temporary files there are after a reboot of a Mac which would justify running that process for like 30 minutes using a lot of CPU power?

On a side note: I was using zoom when I noticed this high CPU usage of "find" and when I stopped zoom that process "find" vanished. Maybe this could be related?

Comment: Sometimes, the OS has to do some work. I would be worried if the process was running for several hours at over 50% CPU. (Don't forget that is a per-core percentage, so the total could be 800% for an 8-core CPU.)

Comment: So it really is normal after a reboot to remove caches etc. which can take 30 minutes? So maybe I turn on the Mac 30 minutes before I start working? Would that be a suitable solution?

Comment: 10% - 40% of ONE CPU core shouldn't slow the whole Mac down. What's the total CPU usage (also look at RAM usage). It's not normal to be doing this all the time, but I would certainly let it run and see if it completes, rather than rebooting it mid-operation.

Comment: Yes, but when I had to reboot the mac because it was too slow, I have to rejoin a zoom call and might use a browser (or two) ...

Comment: Does that really max out your CPU?